# Lost for direction on how to continue building a theme

Tags: themes, comments

I'm a complete beginner to WordPress. I decided to start building a theme. I've got the very basics down (header, sidebar, content, footer) but I just cannot find any direction on where to look for resources for building the rest of the theme (comments, single page, etc).

I don't want to rely on tutorials as they all seem outdated (unsuitable for 3.9)

Am I making a mistake for jumping into this without knowing much PhP in the first place?

Comment: Look at the bundled themes. They are one of the best starting points as they are coded to standard (although it is not the alpha and omega of coding standards). Also abuse the codex. Between the bundled themes and the codex you should get a very good idea to finish of your theme. Remember, the bundled themes and the codex are there to be abused ;-)

Comment: As said , Codex is the best source for almost everything at this stage.Check this page , you will get an idea of WP loads templates [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: reconsider looking at tutorials. They may be outdated. But basics of creating a theme is still haven't changed.

Comment: @Sisir The main thing that concerns me is "hard-coding". I've been told it's bad practice. If I write in a custom class or ID, isn't it going to break the theme?

All I see on tutorials are various classes and ID's such as "masthead" "main-comments" etc.

Comment: that is fine. When you write theme you can add your custom CSS ID or classes. I am not sure why that would be bad practice.

Comment: @Sisir Ok cool. Could you briefly explain the difference between that and hard-coding, please?

Comment: @Rockett, yes you should never hardcode, but you've got the meaning of the term wrong. What hardcoding means in this sense is stuff like URL's, any variable ID like post, category and page ID, basically any variable entity that does not remain the same between two different sites. You can hardcode custom classes and ID if you need them to be static. These classes and ID's belongs to the theme, so there is no way for them to change on another site.